# HTML text with subtitles

Tags: html, css, pdf

I want to create a text (Ultimately in epub/pdf but first in html and then I'll convert it) where under every word there is a translation for that word, just smaller. Here is a picture of what the goal is: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeqiW.png)

My current solution is to put two words together in a div, each word in it's own p, I then apply styles to that to get it to be all in-line, the upper word bigger than the translation and so on. Here is what a word would look like:

```
<div class="twc">
    <p class="word-top">Project</p>
    <p class="word-down">Projekt</p>
</div>
```

This solution seems to be very ineffective. Is there any other way to archieve this? I can't use javascript, since it needs to be convertable to epub, pdf, mobi and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is absolutely fine. You won't make it much better if you want to rely on auto width, which you do. I would just replace `<p>` with another `<div>`. One word doesn't make a real paragraph.